# docker-compose + docker desktop + dev-container and permissions issues

Tags: postgresql, docker, visual-studio-code, docker-compose, timescaledb

Hi i have my projects on a windows 11 box, but my dev environment is linux(bullseye base) environment running in a container using docker desktop
My folder structure looks like this

```
my_proj
    /.devcontainer
    /database
        /postgres
        /schemas
   /src
```

My docker compose looks like this:

```
services:
  web_app:
    container_name: web_app
    image: web_app
    build:
      context: ..
      dockerfile: .devcontainer/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ../..:/workspaces:cached
    command: sleep infinity
    network_mode: service:db

  db:
    image: timescale/timescaledb:latest-pg15
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ../database/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
    ports: 
      - 5050:5000
      - 5432:5432
```

Everything builds fine. and the dev container comes up nicely under visual studio code.
The web_app (dev environment) container runs as user 'vscode' (uid: 1000, gid: 1000)

The /database/postgress volume is so that i dont lose my data if the postgress container goes down.
The /database/schema is where i store my sql as i work on building my database out.

The problem im having are two fold.

1. I am unable to see postgres files under /database/postgres from my ide(vscode ide running as user vscode)
2. I am unable to save any edits to schema files under /database/schemas

When i look at the permissions for database/postgres and files under database/schemas.

- /database has permissions vscode:vscode
- /database/postgres has permissions '70:root'(i am guessing that is coming from some user that the postgress container runs as)
- /database/schemas files have permissions '999:vscode'(i dont know where that is coming from)

From the host, since i am admin on the host, i have made all folders and files rw to everyone.  but the permissions in the container does not reflect those change.

I've also tried adding this to my DockerFile, to no avail:

```
RUN mkdir -p /database/schemas  
RUN chown -R 1000:1000 /database/schemas
RUN setfacl -d -m g::rwx /database/schemas
```

But I do need to edit my sql files under /schemas.
Any help in understanding where that 999 is coming from how to resolve this issue would be appreciated.